# editing video (overlaying text) using AVfoundation is resulting weird behaviour in video

Tags: h.264, quicktime, ios

Whenever I move the pointer you can see video getting weird pixelation.

[image]

Complete video showing how it behaves in quicktime player: https://jmp.sh/TMaknmp

I am just applying overlay using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` in `AVFoundation`.

Video is being created using h264 codec, on iphone 12 device.

I have tried changing codec to hevc but that had no effect.